# Galois solvable and Galois abelian elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $α$ be an element of some extension field of $F$
that is algebraic over $F$. Say that $α $ is Galois solvable over $F$ if $F(α)$ is Galois over $F$ and
$Gal(F(α)/F)$ is a solvable group, and Say that $α$ is Galois abelian over $F$ if $F(α)$ is Galois over
$F$ and $Gal(F(α)/F)$ is an abelian group.

> Prove or give a counterexample:
>
> 1) If $α$ is Galois solvable over $F$ and $β ∈ F(α)$ then $β$ is
>   Galois solvable over $F$.
>
> 2) If $α$ is Galois abelian over $F$ and $β ∈ F(α)$ then $β$ is
>   Galois abelian over $F$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If $G:=\operatorname{Gal}(F(\alpha)/F)$ is solvable, there is even a priori no reason that the intermediate extension $F(\beta)/F$ is Galois. Take for example the splitting field of $X^3-2$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. It has solvable Galois group $S_3$, but $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbf{Q}$ is not Galois.
- If $G$ is abelian, then all intermediate extensions are Galois. By
  the Galois correspondence, $\operatorname{Gal}(F(\beta)/F)$ is a
  quotient of $G$, thus abelian too.

Comment: Thank you, but what are α and β in the first part

Comment: The $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the question....

Comment: "By the Galois correspondence, $\operatorname{Gal}(F(\beta)/F)$ is a
   quotient of $G$, thus abelian too" do we really need  Galois correspondence..since G is abelian any subgroup is abelian.?

Comment: α and β in the example ..$β=2^{1/3}$

Comment: But $\operatorname{Gal}(F(\beta)/F)$ is not a subgroup of $G$, but rather a quotient. In any case, subgroups and quotients of abelian groups are again abelian. And yes, $\beta=\sqrt[3]{2}$ in the example and $\alpha$ is your favorite primitive element of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and advise.

Comment: BUT $ β =2^{1/3}$ does not belong to $F(α )$ α primitive third of unity?

Comment: I'm asking that since the question restrict us in simple extensions "If α is Galois solvable over F and **β∈F(α)** then β is Galois solvable over F"

Comment: Think of the primitive element theorem.